# Hanging an over-the-range microwave without top cabinet

Tags: microwave-oven

I have an over-the-range microwave with wall bracket but no cabinets above.  It is safe to hang it solely by the wall bracket or is the top cabinet to bolt it to a requirement?

If it matters, [this is the microwave in question](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-LMV1680ST)

Comment: Installations instructions for that model are hard to come by.  On the support forum, I see 4-5 requests for it but not a single useful reply.

If you have the wall brackets, are there instructions?  Do they suggest they alone can support the appliance?

Comment: I too saw the requests online.  I even called LG for installation instructions and the best they could do was for me to go back to the place I bought it and see if they have them.  Problem is, I didn't buy it.  I acquired it through a home purchase.  No docs.

Comment: I ended up going with a cabinet above.  I desperately needed to get the microwave up and this was the most direct route.  In the future I may end up switching it up with a shelf, but for now, this works.  Thanks, all.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, BTW. I've been debating whether I wanted to raise (or lose) the middle cabinet when I swapped in the OTR microwave, and I didn't know the issue existed. It does sound like a shelf, suitably bracketed, ought to suffice.

Comment: The only problem with the Ikea shelf I see if the brackets that hang it to the wall. I believe these shelf are not up to the weight of a microwave...maybe under 40 lbs?? How much weight can an Ikea shelf like this take?? Ya you could mount it to the shelf....but would it pull right out of the wall?? Has anyone tried this yet??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have hung a few of this type of microwave, not this particular brand or model, all required the bolts through the upper cabinet. Understandably so, that is a lot of weight hanging off of a thin stamped metal plate.

Answer (score 3):

I just hung a Whirlpool OTR microwave and attaching to the upper cabinet is a requirement.  The lower bracket supports the back of the microwave, but does not keep it from rotating down.  When you install the microwave, you put the back end on the bracket, rotate it up so that the top of the microwave touches the bottom of the cabinet, then hold it while installing the bolts from the upper cabinet.  Two of us were holding it while a third installed the bolts, and it definitely would have fallen without us holding it.

I would install a shelf above the microwave so you can use it to hold up the microwave.  I would then put some diagonal bracing along side the microwave to cover up the sides (not really meant to be visible) and make the shelf stronger by attaching it to the wall below the shelf.  You would definitely want to hit some studs since my microwave weighed well over 50 lbs.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed a couple of these. I don't see how it could possibly hang from just the wall without support from above. If you don't have a cabinet above it, then you need some creative ideas, like maybe constructing a shelf with diagonal bracing back to the wall. If you post a picture of the area, I'm sure the users on SE could come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking a lot about this problem because I am in the same boat.  I think I came up with a solution, but haven't tried it yet.

IKEA sells wall shelves with a hidden metal bracket.  Basically you screw the bracket to the wall, slide the shelf over it, then screw the shelf to the bracket (mainly to keep it from sliding).  They're really easy to install.

In theory you could install the wall shelf first, then follow the instructions for mounting the microwave and use the shelf as support instead of the upper cabinet.  Then you also get some shelf space for some light decorative items or for food boxes.[image]

Comment: Please be sure to report back to let us know if it worked, what pitfalls you ran into, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket already supports to weight all on its own because you just installed the bracket to the studs right. Now get an L bracket install upside down  drill holes for microwave bolts. Now on wall side cut off the wall side of bracket so you only have one to two inches of bracket. Align those two inches to stud and drill holes in it and bolt in to studs, done.

Upper and lower support with minimal bracket view. Just need a carbon leaf to cut bracket and metal drill bit to make holes in bracket and good wall screws.

Comment: I removed the sarcasm from your question so it can stand as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

cut into soffit drywall drill thru board install bolts into microwave top per instructions then refinish soffit.  GUY (CARPENTER)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The original poster didn't mention a soffit; he explicitly said there was nothing above the microwave to attach it to.