# Mounting a microwave w/o the upper cabinet

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I'm working on a kitchen remodel and the designer has asked that the over the stove microwave be mounted under a floating shelf! The shelf has a capacity of 50lb and the microwave weighs 63 lbs. Is there any way I can mount this using perhaps some other support? Is there a way it can be supported solely by the wall bracket? Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Comment: plus the weight of whatever is cooking in the microwave. IMO there is no way to do this with a "floating" shelf, which in my experience sacrifice strength for absence of visible brackets.

Answer (score 3):

The microwave doesn't "dead hang" from the shelf (very little would be able to support a microwave if that were the case). There's typically a mounting bracket you put on the wall and the cabinet holds the front up.

[image]

It should be noted that there's [no way to mount it solely to the wall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44865/hanging-an-over-the-range-microwave-without-top-cabinet) (this quote typifies all the answers)

> I just hung a Whirlpool OTR microwave and attaching to the upper cabinet is a requirement. The lower bracket supports the back of the microwave, but does not keep it from rotating down.

The only way I've seen this done is either with a [bracket or shelf **under** the microwave.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I0QNFI4) (which limits the size)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the manufacturer's installation recommendations. The one we installed (Whirlpool in 2009) used only a single wall bracket, lag bolted to two studs at four points and did not need to be connected to the adjacent cabinets. 
If you install it outside of the manufacturer's instructions,  the manufacturer won't honor the warranty and the homeowner's insurance will hold you liable and pursue (sue) you for any damages or expenses it may incur if the homeowner places a claim.

Answer (score 0):

[image]yes it is possible, the bracket the holds the microwave vertical supports the weight, verify your attaching to studs and use washers for the screws for added rigidity, I then used wall strapping predrilled for the top screws pulled it through the drywall slits I made and attached to blocking I installed between studs wich keeps it from tilting forward then vented the back of microwave up wall and out to attic and outside. strong enough to sit on and not worry.